# where cause on related mode django

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have 2 models

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent,related_name='child')
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    type = models.BooleanField()
```

I want to fetch result from parent model and related records from child

```
Parent.objects.all()
```

it returns me all records form parent and child IN django rest framework but I want only that child which type is ture, how can i add condition

Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

In your Parent generic list api view override the get_queryset method:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return (Parent.objects.all()
            .prefetch_related(Prefetch('child', queryset=Child.objects.filter(type=True))))
```

Also on a side note I suggest you not to name the field `type` on child model since it conflicts with the python keyword `type`. And another suggestion is to use the related_name value as `children`.